# Django 3.0.7 and Djongo Embedded Models - “Models aren't loaded yet”

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

Whenever I try to create an `EmbeddedField`in Django with Djongo I get the below error message.
I tried everything suggested around the web. But I'm absolutely stuck here and need help to overcome that issue.
As soon as I try to `migrate` or try to `runserver` it throws this error. This error starts to appear as soon as I use `EmbeddedField`.
I haven't modified the manage.py file.

## Error Message

```
djongo django.core.expceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

## models.py

```
from djongo import models 

class ClientRepresentation(models.Model):
    client_main_contact = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    client_stand_in_contact = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class User(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    client_location = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    client_representation = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=ClientRepresentation
        # null=True
        )

    objects = models.DjongoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client_name
```

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # REST Framework API
    'rest_framework',

    # Own Apps
    'usr'
]
```

## manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djongotest.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I haven't looked into EmbeddedField, but it looks suspect that a container model can be abstract.

Comment: @Melvyn what do you mean with abstract?

Comment: `abstract = True` as in a template model that cannot live on its own but is an abstraction for reuse in other models.

Comment: @Melvyn I also tried to get rid of the `class Meta` but it didn't change the error message

Comment: I put `abstract = True` into it because these two fields belong to the `User`model and are embedded in the `User` model

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/using-django-with-mongodb-data-fields/), it's correct. However, is `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` pointing to `usr.User`?

Comment: @Melvyn where do you see it pointing to `usr.User` and what do you suggest instead?

Comment: I don't want to create a new User model it could also be named Client, what I by the away also tried. To rename `User`to `Client`

Comment: Not [your problem](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/417) but something in Djongo.

Comment: @Melvyn yeah I've also seen that post, but there seems to be no fix for now. I contacted the developer to give a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem created in version 1.3.2 of Djongo. Installing version 1.3.1 or lower does not exhibit this issue.

You can check by doing: `pip install djongo<1.3.2` and running `python manage.py check` to see if the error occurs.

The error is introduced because of a new validation method added to Djongo 1.3.2 that validates the model container, however it cannot be done at that point in time. The problem [may be fixed](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/blob/master/djongo/models/fields.py#L116) upstream, as the problem was caused in building the reverse relation tree, which can only be done if all reverse models are ready.

Since it is only a validation, you could subclass EmbeddedField and just not call the validation:

```py
from djongo import models


class EmbeddedField(models.EmbeddedField):
    def __init__(self, model_container, model_form_class=None, model_form_kwargs = None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model_container = model_container
        self.model_form_class = model_form_class
        self.model_form_kwargs = {} if model_form_kwargs is None else model_form_kwargs

        # Bypass call to _validate_container()
        super(models.fields.FormlessField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class User(models.Model):
    ...
     client_representation = EmbeddedField(
        model_container=ClientRepresentation
     )
```

Comment: Do you think I therefore should use SQL or MongoEngine as using an older version can be a security concern or cause other issues?

Comment: Go with 1.3.1 till 1.3.3 is out and put some pressure on the maintainers to release 1.3.3 with at least that fix in it. It's quite the showstopper for anyone using Embedded field. Or use a workaround which I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Your awsome! I'll try 1.3.1 and keep this thread posted with news from the developer.

Comment: So I had a short talk and Djongo 1.3.3 is out to try. I'm currently can't log into the admin area with version 1.3.3 and I currently don't now why `Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key`but embedded models don't throw an error I think.

Comment: Yes, that would be unrelated. And not sure how that would relate to the login procedure.